# Chrome browser can not read source map its from Express socket.io

Tags: javascript, express

My problem is :
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://flijfnhifgdcbhglkneplegafminjnhn/content/socket.io.js.map: System error: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

---

MY code is :
/**app.js**/

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const http = require("http");
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const socketIO = require("socket.io");
const io = socketIO(server)
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;


io.on("connection",(socket)=>{
  console.log("connection is completed with web socket");
  console.log("socket is " + socket);
})
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'src')))


server.listen(PORT,()=>{
  console.log(`server is started at port on ${PORT}!`);
})
```

/**index.html**/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script src="js/chat.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

My npm is :
express, nodemon, socket.io, moment

---

I just followed this lecture : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UoKoPP91Qx0 
but doesn't work! help me please :( !
why chorme can't find script source ?

Comment: "source map", not script.

Comment: @Quentin source map :0 ... okay!